# Amazon EC2 Boto: filter by tag substring

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I use tags on my EC2 instances, reservations, etc. to keep track of the different projects / components that they relate to. I would love to programmatically (i.e. using Boto (python) rather than the AWS web interface) be able to filter my instances or reservations or AMIs by tag substring rather than exact tag.

For example:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
all_reservations = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'tag:name':['penguin']})
```

returns a list of instances with the exact name "penguin". Is it possible to do something like:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
all_reservations = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'tag:name_contains':['penguin']})
```

so it returns a list of instances with names like `['emperor_penguin', 'penguin_colony']`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This bit worked for me:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
filtered_instances_list = conn.get_only_instances(filters={'tag:Name':'penguin*'})
```

Tag names are case sensitive... that got me for a few minutes.         ^

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just do this:

```
all_reservations = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'tag:name_contains':['penguin*']})
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Nope, returns a blank list. Same if using 'penguin.*' as the search key. Same when using two '_' characters (like Django).

Comment: That's weird, it seems to work with AWSCLI.  I'll have to investigate a bit more.

Comment: try `(filters={'tag:name_contains':['*penguin*']})` or `(filters={'tag:name_contains':'*penguin*'})`